# Select specific fields on MySQL JSON Array column

Tags: mysql, json

I'm working with MySQL 5.7 and I have a table with the following content in json array format (the column is json type)

```
[{
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "15.066",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.422232",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601537",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:52:07"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "15.066",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.422232",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601537",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:52:07"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "15.178",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4222246",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601528",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:52:53"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "15.53",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4222462",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601327",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:54:13"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "17.906",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4222306",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601535",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:54:24"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "19.69",
    "altitude": "846.1",
    "latitude": "-22.4222719",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601766",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:54:44"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "32.262",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4222971",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4600478",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:54:54"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "17.921",
    "altitude": "846.1",
    "latitude": "-22.4222669",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4600871",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:55:05"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "15.935",
    "altitude": "846.5",
    "latitude": "-22.4225234",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4600278",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:55:26"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "16.631",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4224584",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601033",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:55:46"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "23.679",
    "altitude": "850.9",
    "latitude": "-22.4224691",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.460512",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:56:05"
}, {
    "speed": "1.41",
    "bearing": "200",
    "accuracy": "96",
    "altitude": "864",
    "latitude": "-22.4226247",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4606079",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:56:21"
}, {
    "speed": "3.41",
    "bearing": "204",
    "accuracy": "17.156",
    "altitude": "845.4",
    "latitude": "-22.4225045",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4608494",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:56:32"
}, {
    "speed": "1.49",
    "bearing": "10",
    "accuracy": "21.788",
    "altitude": "870",
    "latitude": "-22.4226205",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4608641",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:56:42"
}, {
    "speed": "0.56",
    "bearing": "168",
    "accuracy": "11.504",
    "altitude": "845.9",
    "latitude": "-22.4225273",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4609705",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:56:53"
}, {
    "speed": "0.8",
    "bearing": "162",
    "accuracy": "15.277",
    "altitude": "859",
    "latitude": "-22.4226706",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4610013",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:57:04"
}, {
    "speed": "0.53",
    "bearing": "210",
    "accuracy": "10.935",
    "altitude": "845.9",
    "latitude": "-22.4227521",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4610716",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:57:15"
}, {
    "speed": "2.1",
    "bearing": "106",
    "accuracy": "10.484",
    "altitude": "851",
    "latitude": "-22.4228718",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.461021",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:57:25"
}, {
    "speed": "1.24",
    "bearing": "103",
    "accuracy": "10.389",
    "altitude": "845.9",
    "latitude": "-22.4228844",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4609035",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:57:36"
}, {
    "speed": "1.3",
    "bearing": "88",
    "accuracy": "8.929",
    "altitude": "847",
    "latitude": "-22.4229512",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4607325",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:57:46"
}, {
    "speed": "1.15",
    "bearing": "92",
    "accuracy": "7.666",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.4229594",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4605854",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:57:56"
}, {
    "speed": "0.59",
    "bearing": "107",
    "accuracy": "10.135",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.4229556",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4604829",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:58:07"
}, {
    "speed": "0.88",
    "bearing": "123",
    "accuracy": "13.445",
    "altitude": "848",
    "latitude": "-22.4229739",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4603345",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:58:18"
}, {
    "speed": "0.83",
    "bearing": "99",
    "accuracy": "11.624",
    "altitude": "848",
    "latitude": "-22.4230001",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4602456",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:58:29"
}, {
    "speed": "0.32",
    "bearing": "117",
    "accuracy": "10.344",
    "altitude": "847",
    "latitude": "-22.4229103",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4600981",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:58:39"
}, {
    "speed": "0.62",
    "bearing": "337",
    "accuracy": "10.671",
    "altitude": "850",
    "latitude": "-22.4228718",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4600887",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:58:49"
}, {
    "speed": "0.74",
    "bearing": "2",
    "accuracy": "10.088",
    "altitude": "854",
    "latitude": "-22.4227985",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601105",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:59:00"
}, {
    "speed": "1.03",
    "bearing": "61",
    "accuracy": "9.095",
    "altitude": "853",
    "latitude": "-22.4226627",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4600776",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:59:10"
}, {
    "speed": "1.02",
    "bearing": "75",
    "accuracy": "8.453",
    "altitude": "849",
    "latitude": "-22.4225036",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4599527",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:59:21"
}, {
    "speed": "1.32",
    "bearing": "104",
    "accuracy": "8.653",
    "altitude": "850",
    "latitude": "-22.4225338",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4598042",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:59:31"
}, {
    "speed": "1.67",
    "bearing": "112",
    "accuracy": "9.096",
    "altitude": "851",
    "latitude": "-22.4225277",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4596597",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:59:41"
}, {
    "speed": "0.81",
    "bearing": "122",
    "accuracy": "8.18",
    "altitude": "852",
    "latitude": "-22.4225687",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4595177",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 09:59:52"
}, {
    "speed": "0.25",
    "bearing": "349",
    "accuracy": "8.115",
    "altitude": "848",
    "latitude": "-22.4224948",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4594104",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:00:02"
}, {
    "speed": "0.84",
    "bearing": "8",
    "accuracy": "7.258",
    "altitude": "851",
    "latitude": "-22.4223685",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4593301",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:00:13"
}, {
    "speed": "1.3",
    "bearing": "27",
    "accuracy": "7.495",
    "altitude": "853",
    "latitude": "-22.4222186",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.45924",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:00:24"
}, {
    "speed": "0.92",
    "bearing": "295",
    "accuracy": "7.523",
    "altitude": "853",
    "latitude": "-22.4220675",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4592253",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:00:35"
}, {
    "speed": "0.78",
    "bearing": "281",
    "accuracy": "8.106",
    "altitude": "855",
    "latitude": "-22.4220202",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.459321",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:00:46"
}, {
    "speed": "1.14",
    "bearing": "288",
    "accuracy": "9.973",
    "altitude": "854",
    "latitude": "-22.4219788",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4594899",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:00:56"
}, {
    "speed": "1.16",
    "bearing": "249",
    "accuracy": "9.212",
    "altitude": "854",
    "latitude": "-22.4219823",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4596335",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:01:07"
}, {
    "speed": "0.85",
    "bearing": "279",
    "accuracy": "8.984",
    "altitude": "853",
    "latitude": "-22.4219532",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4597928",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:01:18"
}, {
    "speed": "0.7",
    "bearing": "279",
    "accuracy": "8.711",
    "altitude": "851",
    "latitude": "-22.4219901",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.459913",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:01:28"
}, {
    "speed": "1.44",
    "bearing": "168",
    "accuracy": "7.527",
    "altitude": "849",
    "latitude": "-22.4220831",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4599281",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:01:38"
}, {
    "speed": "1.11",
    "bearing": "187",
    "accuracy": "6.462",
    "altitude": "847",
    "latitude": "-22.4222045",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4599489",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:01:49"
}, {
    "speed": "0.68",
    "bearing": "273",
    "accuracy": "5.613",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.422261",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4600133",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:01:59"
}, {
    "speed": "0.74",
    "bearing": "37",
    "accuracy": "5.745",
    "altitude": "845",
    "latitude": "-22.4222299",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601316",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:02:10"
}, {
    "speed": "0.19",
    "bearing": "39",
    "accuracy": "5.053",
    "altitude": "844",
    "latitude": "-22.4222222",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601505",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:02:20"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "4.267",
    "altitude": "844",
    "latitude": "-22.4222281",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.460153",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:02:31"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "5.254",
    "altitude": "844",
    "latitude": "-22.4222282",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601531",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:02:42"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "4.659",
    "altitude": "845",
    "latitude": "-22.422224",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601606",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:02:53"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "5.091",
    "altitude": "845",
    "latitude": "-22.4222237",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601613",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:03:04"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "5.385",
    "altitude": "845",
    "latitude": "-22.4222237",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601613",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:03:15"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "8.568",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4222306",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601694",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:03:26"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "8.981",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4222246",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601666",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:03:36"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "8.969",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4222239",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601661",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:03:47"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "8.847",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4222231",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601668",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:03:58"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "8.845",
    "altitude": "846.1",
    "latitude": "-22.4222241",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601667",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:04:07"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "9.471",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4222266",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601659",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:04:19"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "9.561",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4222243",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601665",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:04:30"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "9.502",
    "altitude": "0",
    "latitude": "-22.4222244",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601664",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:04:40"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "7.485",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.4222196",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601626",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:04:51"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "8.104",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.4222181",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601614",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:05:02"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "7.36",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.422218",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601614",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:05:13"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "6.431",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.422218",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601614",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:05:24"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "6.755",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.422218",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601614",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:05:35"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "7.718",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.422218",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601614",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:05:46"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "7.284",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.422218",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601614",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:05:56"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "6.899",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.422218",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601614",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:06:07"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "6.673",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.422218",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601614",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:06:18"
}, {
    "speed": "0",
    "bearing": "0",
    "accuracy": "6.348",
    "altitude": "846",
    "latitude": "-22.422218",
    "provider": "fused",
    "longitude": "-45.4601614",
    "timestamp": "12/11/2019 10:06:29"
}
```

I want to select latitude and longitude of the elements that have speed != 0.
I tried using JSON_EXTRACT, JSON_CONTAINS, path expressions and I can't get what I need using only queries.

I can't have 1 location per row because it will blow up my database, that's why I'm storing all locations from one route in a single row.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I know that our production database can store millions of locations each day considering that our app tracks the user's location every 10 seconds every day.

Comment: And you believe that it's somehow more efficient to store millions of records in a single huge string rather than in a way, which databases are designed for?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It's not a single huge string. It's a single row per route with a couple hundred of locations each row.

Comment: That doesn't matter much. If you have any issues with one row per location, you will have even more issues with this design. Your question is just one of them. Something that could be a trivial SELECT query now becomes very complex and inefficient.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yeah I'm starting to notice that. I'm having more trouble trying to figure out how to work with our design than if we would change our design to work properly.